# N-dimensional array considered as 0 dimensional array

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy

while plotting the graph for differential equations the numpy array x which should store about 1001 values(using linspace command) is considered as a 0 dimensional array. Even printing the type of array x returns 'numpy.ndarray' but error arises as
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed

The function "model" where is this issue is occurring is:

```
def model(uv, x, alpha):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    print("Type of x:", type(x))
    u, v = uv[0], uv[1]
    dx = x[1] - x[0]

    # Calculate first derivatives using finite differences
    dudx = np.gradient(u, dx)
    dvdx = np.gradient(v, dx)
    # Calculate second derivatives using central difference formula

    dudx2 = np.gradient(dudx, dx)
    dvdx2 = np.gradient(dvdx, dx)

    dudt = u * (1 - u - v) + alpha * dudx2
    dvdt = -u * v + alpha * dvdx2
    return [dudt, dvdt]
```

I tried tracing the where the issue occurs using print statements but failed to find it. I need the issue to be rectified to plot the graph.

Comment: Your question is missing a [mre] of a dataset that triggers the described behavior.

Comment: You don't give us any clues  about `x` before the `asarray` call.  Is it an array?  If so what's the shape and dtype?  `asarray` applied to objects that aren't iterable (list, tuple, other arrays) will produce a `()` shape with `object` dtype.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.